# Object creation without lvalue in C++

Tags: c++

Why the below code is working without any compilation error? I was expecting compilation error at `line no 18` because I am not assigning object to any lvalue.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{

public:
    explicit A()
    {
     cout<<"constructor\n";
    }
    ~A()
    {
     cout<<"destructor\n";
    }

};

int main()
{
    A(); //line no 18
}
```

Comment: Your class does not accept (or stores) any values.. hence the result.

Comment: The compiler is not supposed to give an error in such a case because you can do things inside the constructor which might be in no way related to the creation of an object (just like in this case, the constructor only prints out `"constructor"` to the console). The best you can do is force the compiler to give a warning by putting a C++17 attribute called `[[nodiscard]]` before the constructor declaration.

Comment: Why did you say "lvalue" rather than "value"?

Comment: @Ruks - That's a great answer. Why did you post it in the comment section?

Answer (score 2):

> Why the below code is working without any compilation error? I was expecting compilation error at line no 18 because I am not assigning object with any lvalue.

The compiler is not supposed to give an error in such a case because you can do things inside the constructor which might be in no way related to the creation of an object (just like in this case, the constructor only prints out "constructor" to the console).

The best you can do is force the compiler to give a warning by putting a C++17 attribute called `[[nodiscard]]` before the constructor declaration:

```cpp
class A {
    // [[nodiscard]] only works on compilers which support C++17 or above
    [[nodiscard]] explicit A() {
        // ...
    }

// ...
};


int main() {
    A(); // Will give a warning
}
```